# How to migrate sequelize association?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I add a new table to an existing database. I create association in the model, and `createTable()` in the migration file. After `db:migrate` and `sync()` association not created in database.
How to create assotiation witchout `sync({force: true})` in existing database?

**Model and migration:**

```
//new model
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define('batchOfDrivers', {
    id:        {
      type:          DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey:    true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  }, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    tableName:       'batch_of_drivers',
    classMethods:    {
      associate: models => {
        models.batchOfDrivers.hasMany(models.drivers, {
          foreignKey: 'batchId',
          onDelete: 'cascade'
        });
      }
    }
  });
};


//migration
module.exports = {
  up: function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return [
      sequelize.createTable(
        'batchOfDrivers',
        {
          id: {
            type:          DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey:    true,
            autoIncrement: true
          }
        }
      )
    ];
  },

  down: function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return [
      sequelize.removeTable('batchOfDrivers')
    ];
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you post the migration script and the model definitions?

Comment: Here: http://codepaste.net/ix3jav

Comment: And when the server starts, I do `models.sequelize.sync()`.

Comment: Couple of follow up questions: 1) The `.associate()` function is called by the generated `models/index.js` file (or wherever directory you put your models in). Are you calling `require('models')`?
2) `hasMany` puts the foreign key on the other table, is that what you intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Model that you are creating has a `hasMany()` association with the 'drivers' table. The `has*` methods in sequelize put the foreign key on the other ('target') table.

In your case, the target table already exists, so the foreign key will needs to be added using an `ALTER TABLE` statement. You should add that to your migration script

```
    //migration
module.exports = {
up: function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return [
    sequelize.createTable(
      'batchOfDrivers',
      {
        id: {
          type:          DataTypes.INTEGER,
          primaryKey:    true,
          autoIncrement: true
        }
      }
    ),
    // This may require 2 ALTER statements or have another syntax, depends on your DB
    sequelize.query('ALTER TABLE drivers ADD batchId INTEGER, ADD FOREIGN KEY batchId REFERENCES batchOfDrivers(id);')
  ];
},  

down: function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return [
    sequelize.removeTable('batchOfDrivers'),
    // Again, this ALTER statement is going to vary by DB
    sequelize.query('ALTER TABLE drivers DROP constraint drivers_batchId_fk, DROP column batchId;')
  ];
}
```

This, often enough, will require you to drop the table first. When you force the synchronize method `.sync({force: true})`, this is what its doing. Depends on the DB you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [umzug](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug)
It's quite easy to programmatically execute migrations using it

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to solve the problem by means of the Sequelize.